# Why is this docopt string not working either with or without optional args?

Tags: docopt

Here is the complete docopt string I used:

```
foo.

Usage:
    foo [options] <file> -o <output>
    foo --help | --version

Options:
    -h, --help          print this help message.
    --target <target>   target.
    --version           print the version.
```

According to [the official parser](http://try.docopt.org/?doc=foo.%0D%0A%0D%0AUsage%3A%0D%0A++++foo+%5Boptions%5D+%3Cfile%3E+-o+%3Coutput%3E%0D%0A++++foo+--help+%7C+--version%0D%0A%0D%0AOptions%3A%0D%0A++++-h%2C+--help++++++++++print+this+help+message.%0D%0A++++--target+%3Ctarget%3E+++target%0D%0A++++--version+++++++++++print+the+version.&argv=foo+a+-o+b), either `foo a -o b` or `foo --target abc a -o b` is not correctly parsed. What could be possible reasons for this case? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure about the allowed combinations of options for your script, but here's something that should be close.

Just for fun, I wrote a script that has similar options to yours to test this out with the latest [docopts](https://github.com/docopt/docopts).

I found it simplest to write just `[options]` in the main Usage section, and have all the options below as alternatives, with no specific combinations required.

I'm on macOS so I'm using bash 3.2 (with patched `docopts.sh` to fix some Mac issues).  You can avoid some of the code in this script if you're on bash 4.x - see the commented-out section with `--auto` option and `docopt_print_ARGS` function.  Currently you would need bash 4.x to avoid patching `docopts.sh`.

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# foo.
#
# Usage:
#     foo [options] <file>
#     foo --help | --version
#
# Options:
#     -t, --target <target>   target.
#     -o, --output <output>   output.
#     -h, --help              print this help message.
#     --version               print the version.
#

# bash 3.2 (patched docopts.sh) - include set -x to see the args easily
source docopts.sh
usage=$(docopt_get_help_string "$0")
set -x
eval "$(docopts -G ARGS -V "$VERSION" -h "$usage" : "$@")"

# On bash 4.x, replace preceding section with this, or use -A instead of -G above
# source docopts.sh --auto "$@"
# docopt_print_ARGS
```

This parses the Usage section OK and processes command lines such as:

```
foo --target a -o b file1
foo --target a --output b file1
foo --target a file1
```

Partial output with `set -x` to show args processed correctly:

```
$ ./foo --target a file1 --output b
...
++ ARGS_target=a
++ ARGS_output=b
++ ARGS_file=file1
++ ARGS_help=false
++ ARGS_version=false
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for @RichVel's efforts. Yesterday I finally found out the underlying (stupid) cause for this problem.

In the official online parser  the first part, i.e. `foo` shouldn't be used. `--target abc a -o b` works fine in the online example.

Regarding my question, the bug actually comes from that docopt.rs stores `--target abc` in `flag_target` instead of `arg_target`.

Comment: Glad my answer helped.  Actually that behaviour in online parser does make sense - in the code I posted, the `eval` line includes `"$@"` which corresponds to all the arguments from `$1` upwards, but not the name of the script (`$1`) e.g. `foo`.  The online parser is doing the same thing.